# How to "listen" to a multiprocessing queue in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing

I will start with the code, I hope it is simple enough:

```
import Queue
import multiprocessing


class RobotProxy(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, commands_q):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)

        self.commands_q = commands_q


    def run(self):
        self.listen()
        print "robot started"


    def listen(self):

        print "listening"
        while True:
            print "size", self.commands_q.qsize()
            command = self.commands_q.get()
            print command
            if command is "start_experiment":
                self.start_experiment()
            elif command is "end_experiment":
                self.terminate_experiment()
                break
            else: raise Exception("Communication command not recognized")
        print "listen finished"


    def start_experiment(self):
        #self.vision = ds.DropletSegmentation( )
        print "start experiment"


    def terminate_experiment(self):
        print "terminate experiment"



if __name__ == "__main__":

    command_q = Queue.Queue()
    robot_proxy = RobotProxy( command_q )
    robot_proxy.start()
    #robot_proxy.listen()
    print "after start"
    print command_q.qsize()
    command_q.put("start_experiment")
    command_q.put("end_experiment")
    print command_q.qsize()

    raise SystemExit
```

So basically I launch a process, and I want this process to listen to commands put on the Queue.

When I execute this code, I get the following:

```
after start
0
2
listening
size 0
```

it seems that I am not sharing the Queue properly, or that I am doing any other error. The program gets stuck forever in that "self.commands_q.get() when in theory the queue has 2 elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use multiprocessing.Queue instead of Queue.Queue in order to have the Queue object be shared across processes.

See here: [Multiprocessing Queues](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)